# I typed If,if,else code but output is statements of If and else

Tags: c++

I am getting

```
a is positive
a is negative
```

when i give input `5`

I expect answer to be only

```
a is positive
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int a;
  cout<<"Enter the value of a:";
  cin>>a;
  if (a>0){
    cout<<"a is positive"<<endl;
  }
  if (a==0){
    cout<<"a is zero"<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<"a is negative"<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: The last `else` branch will be executed if `a` doesn't equal zero, does that apply for `5`? What do you think, why did you expect something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two separate condition blocks:

```cpp
    if (a > 0) {
        cout << "a is positive" << endl;
    }
```

Then after that you check again, and since `5` is not `0`, it'll print that it's negative.

```
    if (a == 0) {
        cout << "a is zero" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "a is negative" << endl;
    }
```

Connect them with an `else` to get the wanted output:

```cpp
    if (a > 0) {
        cout << "a is positive" << endl;
    } else if (a == 0) {
//    ^^^^
        cout << "a is zero" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "a is negative" << endl;
    }
```

---

Sidenote: if `a` had been a floating point variable, like `float` or `double`, you'd want to avoid comparing for equality (because floating points are tricky). In that case you'd make the *greater than* and *less than* first and let the last option be equality:

```cpp
    if (a > 0) {
        cout << "a is positive" << endl;
    } else if (a < 0) {
        cout << "a is negative" << endl;        
    } else {
        cout << "a is zero" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `else` (negative) situation is applied only to the second `if (a == 0)` and therefore `if (a != 0)`, which is true, the `else` is run.

```
if (a > 0) {...} //the program checks if a > 0
if (a == 0) {...} //then it checks whether a == 0
else {...} //finally, it decides that a (5) != 5, so it runs also the else branch
```

If you want to have it correct, you should use `if (a > 0)`, then `else if (a == 0)`, then `else`.

I would do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    
    if (a > 0) {
        std::cout << "a is positive. " << std::endl;
    }
    else if (a == 0) {
        std::cout << "a is zero. " << std::endl;
    }
    else { //if a < 0
        std::cout << "a is negative. " << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `else` before `if (a==0)`. Should be:

```
if (a>0){
  cout<<"a is positive"<<endl;
}
else if (a==0){ // add this `else`
  cout<<"a is zero"<<endl;
}
else{
  cout<<"a is negative"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if` incorrectly. Use `if` then `else if` then `else`. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int a;
  cout<<"Enter the value of a:";
  cin>>a;
  if (a>0){
    cout<<"a is positive"<<endl;
  }
  else if (a==0){
    cout<<"a is zero"<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<"a is negative"<<endl;
  }
}
```

With your code, `if` is getting evaluated twice. That is why it is first checking for `if` condition and then again it checks for `if` and `else` condition. Hope this helps.

Comment: can i use If and if?.....like I cant use IF IF Else...is IF IF correct?

Comment: yes, so 'if..else' is one block and similarly 'if' is one block. That is why your code is checking for 2 different conditions. One is for 'if' and then again for 'if else'

Comment: thank you and everyone, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate `if` conditions that are both being evaluated regardless of what the input actually is.

The first condition is always evaluated:

```
if (a > 0) {
    cout << "a is positive" << endl;
}
```

It prints only if the input is positive, otherwise doesn't print anything.

Then the second condition is also always evaluated:

```
if (a == 0) {
    cout << "a is zero" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "a is negative" << endl;
}
```

It always prints something, but it prints the *wrong* thing if the input is positive.

You don't want the 2nd `if..else` to be evaluated at all if the 1st `if` evaluates as true.  So you need to connect the two conditions with another `else`, eg:

```
if (a>0){
  cout<<"a is positive"<<endl;
}
else { // <-- add this!
  if (a==0){
    cout<<"a is zero"<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<"a is negative"<<endl;
  }
}
```

And in this case, the curly braces on the 1st `else` are optional <sup>1</sup>, so you can remove them, eg:

```
if (a>0){
  cout<<"a is positive"<<endl;
}
else if (a==0){
  cout<<"a is zero"<<endl;
}
else{
  cout<<"a is negative"<<endl;
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: actually, all of the curly braces on all of the `if..else if..else` blocks are optional in this example.